# Match a hash created in C# with sql

Tags: c#, sql, hash

I have a method used to generate a hash:

```
public static string GetMD5Hash(string input)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

        bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);

        System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        foreach (byte b in bs)
        {
            s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
        }
        return s.ToString();
    }
```

I then save that hash in a varchar(255) column. Knowing what the original input string was, would it be possible to to arrive at the same hash value stored in the varchar(255) column, using sql (2005)??

I have tried like crazy using different data types, conversions and the hashbytes() function, but have not been able to get close.

Example of my failed attempt :(

```
select convert(varchar, hashbytes('MD5', convert(varbinary(200), '<censored>',0)))
```

Comment: Don't use MD5; it's insecure.

Comment: why `varchar(255)` ? `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` returns a 16 byte array from `ComputeHash()` so you should use char(32) (if you save it as hex that is)

Comment: maybe it's because of ToLower()?

Comment: @Slaks - It may be that this is not a security issue and perhaps the OP is using the hash as a kind of checksum or to quickly locate records in the DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from #c with "bleepbloop" : `04d3f95947702213e23730a0e8fac6c3`

Then

```
select convert(varchar(32), hashbytes('MD5', 'bleepbloop'), 2)

>> 04D3F95947702213E23730A0E8FAC6C3
```

Or You could just store & compare as binary.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `x2` is getting the hex *encoding* of the data, where-as `convert` is getting your server's configured *decoding* of the bytes (which isn't really valid, since that data is not text-based). Very different things. If you keep as varbinary and compare to a `byte[]` you should be fine.

If you are using SQL Server 2008, you can also use:

```
select convert(varchar(32), hashbytes('MD5', convert(varbinary(200),
           '<censored>',0)), 2)
```

to get the hex-encoded version (you can use `1` instead of `2` to get a leading `0x`)

Comment: Thanks for the response and extra info.