# convert SQL Hash Bytes binary value (Multiple datatype fields combination) to c# equivalent

Tags: c#, sql, database, hash, hashbytes

I have formed a hash key with the help of HashBytes as below with the multiple fields combination on SQL.

```
hashbytes('MD5', PID+PNumber+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),cast(datestamp as  binary)) +CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TCount)+OCD+OSeqNbr+TID) AS VARBINARY(80)
```

All the above fileds datatypes are below

```
PID - nvarhcar(30)
PNumber - nvarhcar(30)
datestamp  - Datetime 
TCount  - Int
OCD - varhcar(2)
OSeqNbr - varhcar(10)
TID  - nvarhcar(100)
```

But i need C# equivalent function to get the value , so that i can get the value using c# code on the field values and then passes value to sql then compare the value against to the hash key column.

I have tried as below to get the byte[] value which is equivalent to the hash key binary value. But it is not the same value as sql hash key value.

```
var key = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Event.PID + Event.PNumber +
                                                     Event.DateStamp + Event.TCount +
                                                     Event.OCD + Event.OSeqNbr +
                                                     Event.TID);
```

Can anybody help on this what i am missing?

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (This seems to be a product specific question.)

Comment: Have you tried to search for something like "c# hashbytes md5" ? [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6506910/1997232).

Comment: Yes I did. What i found is they are doing on single column. But i need to have it on multiple columns with different datatypes so here it is not matching

Comment: Actully the datetime conversion is causing problem which i did while generating hashbytes to avoid the Non deterministic  error. But becuse of that i am not able to get c# equivalent now. Any workaround please?   CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),cast(datestamp as  binary))

Comment: Here is the info why i made datetime as binary    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722783/hashbytes-with-datetime2-field?noredirect=1#comment64821906_38722783.            But i got strucked now to get the c# equivalent  value. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146636/how-do-i-calculate-the-equivalent-to-sql-server-hashbytessha1-columnname